# Will GHC strip out unused imports?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When I don’t use certain imports from the `main` function (which should be easily detectable), will GHC strip out the corresponding bindings?

Example:

```
import Text.Parsec (parse)
import My.Testframework (test)

main = parse …

tests = test …
```

Will `My.Testframework` be linked in the executable?

Comment: I would suggest an explicit `module Main (main) where`, to be sure the imports are not re-exported, which would force linking.

Comment: @chi `module Main (main) where` is the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this simple test:

```
import Data.Map as M
import Data.Text as T

main = do
  let m = M.fromList [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
  putStrLn $ show m
```

and got:

```
$ ghc imports.hs
$ $ ls -l imports
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 erik  staff  1583112 May 17 10:56 imports
```

---

I then commented out the unused `Data.Text` import:

```
import Data.Map as M
-- import Data.Text as T

main = do
  let m = M.fromList [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
  putStrLn $ show m
```

and got this:

```
$ ghc imports.hs 
$ ls -l imports
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 erik  staff  1583112 May 17 10:56 imports
```

Nothing changed, so I must assume `Data.Text` was already ignored since it was unused.

---

I then tried 2 more variants.

Leaving in the `Data.Map` import and the `fromList` call, but not using the value in `m`:

```
import Data.Map as M
-- import Data.Text as T

main = do
  let m = M.fromList [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
  putStrLn "hello"
```

which got me:

```
$ ghc imports.hs 
$ ls -l imports
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 erik  staff  1505292 May 17 10:56 imports
```

---

I then also removed the construction of `m` using `fromList`:

```
import Data.Map as M
-- import Data.Text as T

main = do
  putStrLn "hello"
```

which got me:

```
$ ghc imports.hs 
$ ls -l imports
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 erik  staff  1505284 May 17 10:56 imports
```

— the size barely changed.

So my interpretation is that even if you're importing a library and using it superficially, but the use itself is unused, **GHC will not link libraries whose imports are unused.**